# Spring boot HikariPool failed to stop

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

While starting the application I'm getting the HikariPool-1 housekeeper issue.

```
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
```

can anyone help me with this?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836059/the-web-application-appears-to-have-started-a-thread-named-hikaripool-1-houseke

Comment: @JCompetence I have already gone through that question but no solutions of it worked for me, do you have any other solution that might work?